# How to get rid of rEFInd?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot

I wanted to try to install Ubuntu, but since I didn't have an available USB I searched how to do it without USB or CD in  [this post.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/484434/install-ubuntu-without-cd-and-usb-how)

I have a UEFI device so decided to follow through, After making the partition and all that I encountered I couldn't change the partition size, so I decided to copy the content from that one into an unused partition that had 8 GB of memory. Well I had to reboot and I encountered the issue.

rEFInd appears as my boot and I have no OS to choose from, ended up having to use a USB device to solve the issue by booting into Windows installation program and using the repair system option.

Now I wanted to get rid of rEFInd, but I don't know how to do it, and I'm also scared of removing that `S:` partition because the boot is located there. I figured out I could use this command:"bcdedit /set '{bootmgr}' path \Windows\Boot\EFI\bootmgr.efi", but it gives me an error saying:

> element's data type not recognised or it doesn't apply to the specified entry

Execute "bcdedit /?" to obtain help  with the command line :

> Element not found
>   *(I manually translated this so maybe some words aren't the usual ones in English)*

So if anyone knows how to do this I'd be very grateful. It isn't a matter of life or death, since I can finally boot to Windows with no issue, but I'd like to get rid of this.

Comment: How did you manage to boot to Windows?

Comment: Inserted Windows installation USB and selected repair system. There was a setting that said something around "booting problems" clicked there and then Windows appeared in rEFInd. After that everything went fine, though I still want to get rid of it. Also if I use secure boot rEFInd doesn't start since I guess it detects it isn't a very safe software in their terms, not very important info though that might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of posts on our site which could help here.

The post
[Reconstructing Windows EFI files in /boot partition](https://superuser.com/questions/1110644/reconstructing-windows-efi-files-in-boot-partition-linuxwindows-dual-boot)
has [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1111656/8672)
which lets you assign the EFI partition a drive letter and restore the Windows boot
environment.

If this is not enough, you could now access the EFI partition via this drive letter
and delete rEFInd as described in
[this answer](https://superuser.com/a/825334/8672).